# iPhone: How can I have my refresh UIBarButtonItem change to UIActivityIndicator while task is running?

Tags: ios, xcode, refresh

I have a refresh button that executes a function to initiate a request and receive a response.  While it's parsing the response I'm changing my last updated text to keep the user informed on what is going on.  I'm hoping though to have the refresh button become the uiactivityindicator while the "procedure" is running.  How can I accomplish this?  Here is a screenshot of my storyboard to help you get and idea of the setup.  Let me know if I can provide anything else. Thanks!

[image: storyboard image]

Image below shows how I created the bottom bar through the simulated metrics drop down list to the right.

[image: bottom toolbar]

EDIT:

Here is the altered code I used from the marked answer.

```
// Create UIActivityIndicator UIBarButtonItem
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[activityView startAnimating];
UIBarButtonItem *loadingView = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityView];

// Toolbar with LoadingView and LastUpdatedTitle with Flex Spacing
[self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:(NSArray *)[NSArray arrayWithObjects: loadingView, self.flexSpaceOne, self.lastUpdated, self.flexSpaceTwo, nil]];
```

When I wanted to change it back I simply "reset" my items using the same `setItems:arrayWithObjets:` method.  Except that time I would change out the loadingview with self.refreshButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define some ivars to access your toolbar and its items:

```
NSMutableArray *toolbarItems;
IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;
```

Then, in your method where you kick off the task,

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];
UIBarButtonItem *loadingView = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityView];
[toolbarItems replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:loadingView];
toolbar.items = toolbarItems;
```

Then do the reverse when it is done to add your refresh button again.

Comment: Thanks @Coneybeare, but I'm having trouble linking up the *toolbar with my bottom toolbar.  If you look at my 2nd screenshot I add the bottom toolbar under simulated metrics. Yet I don't see how I can select the toolbar to do a Ctrl+Click to link it with the variable.

Comment: You can also access it as navigationcontroller.toolbar. I would suggest reading up on IB or asking a different SO question

Comment: I had to do it a little differently to get it to work, but this showed me the general idea and got me going. I appreciate it! If anyone else is interested in the way I accomplished it I'm going to add it to my original post. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good time to use blocks and start another thread.

```
- (IBAction)refresh:(id)sender
{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[BarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:spinner]; 
    dispatch_queue_t request = dispatch_queue_create("request data", NULL);
        dispatch_async(request, ^{
            // call the method to request data
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = sender;
                // populate the table with the data
        });
    });
    dispatch_release(request);
}
```

You'll notice (of course) that I haven't put the spinner where you want it. That's because I'm not confident about how to access the tool bar items -- but hopefully this will put you on the right track.

Comment: I see that @coneybeare knows how to access the tool bar. Check his answer for that. I still think you should start another thread, though, when you're fetching data over the network. :)

Comment: Of course, but that isn't what this question is about at all. He is asking how to change out the UIBarButtonItem. How he sets up his data is for a different SO question.

Comment: Point taken, but I feel that threads are relevant here because @daveomcd wants to show the spinner and change his "last updated" text to keep the user up-to-date "**while** it's parsing the response."

Comment: Everything is relevant to everything else. SO is for specific answers to specific questions, not discussions on related topics. This helps keep the site organized and clean. Because you didn't address the main question (how to replace the refresh button with a spinner) I feel that this is not a quality answer.